# Android: Check If Selected Database .db File Is Valid

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sqlite

In my app, I can replace current database with another file selected by the user.

I just want a way to check if the file the user selected is a valid database file.

I let the user select a file like this:

```
    private fun selectDbFile() {
    val intent: Intent
    val selectIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).apply {
        addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        type = "*/*" 
    }
    intent = Intent.createChooser(selectIntent, "Choose a file")
    intentLauncher.launch(intent)
}
```

and the intentLauncher is defined like this:

```
    private var intentLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
    if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) { 
        val data: Intent? = result.data
        val uri = data?.data
        uri?.let{
            UtilityKt.replaceCurrentDb(requireContext(), uri) {
                showSuccessAlert()
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

The method that replaces the old db file with a new one is like this:

```
    fun replaceCurrentDb(context: Context, newDbUri: Uri?, completion: () -> Unit) {
    newDbUri?.let {  newUri ->
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            // Do background work
            try {
                val currentDb = context.getDatabasePath(MenuSQLiteHelper.DATABASE_NAME)
                if (currentDb.exists()) {
                    val src = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(newUri)
                    val dst = FileOutputStream(currentDb)
                    val buffer = ByteArray(8 * 1024)
                    src?.copyTo(dst, buffer.size)
                    src?.close()
                    dst.close()
                    // Back to main thread
                    launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                        completion()
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (e: IOException) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Operation failed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                Log.e("DOWNLOAD FAIL!!!", " EXCEPTION IS:", e)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine only if the user selects a valid .db file, but if he selects, for example, an image, the app crashes because wrong data was written to destination.

Comment: Why would you not check the header bytes of the file first? https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html (Offset 0 size 16 bytes - The header string: "SQLite format 3\000"), now schema .. that would be a different error to catch ..

Answer (score 1):

> I just want a way to check if the file the user selected is a valid database file.

If you mean **any SQLite database** then you can check the header, the first 16 bytes will be **"SQLite format 3\000"**. Here's an example of a function that checks this:-

```
private fun isFileSQLiteDatabase(f: File): Boolean {
    val SQLITEFILEHEADER = "SQLite format 3\u0000"
    val fis: InputStream
    if (!f.isFile) return false
    val header = ByteArray(16)
    try {
        fis = FileInputStream(f)
        fis.read(header)
        if (String(header) != SQLITEFILEHEADER) {
            fis.close()
            return false
        } else {
            fis.close()
        }
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

- You may wish to have a look at https://sqlite.org/fileformat.html

**However**, if you want to ensure that it is not **ANY** SQLite Database, for example one that adheres to a set schema, then you would need to undertake a more in-depth check, such as checking that the tables and or other entities (triggers, indexes, views) are as expected.

For example, the following function, passed an array of the expected entity names by interrogating the schema (i.e. sqlite_master):-

```
private fun isDBValid(f: File, entityList: Array<String>): Boolean {

    var matchcount = 0
    if (!isFileSQLiteDatabase(f)) return false
    try {
        val db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(f.path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE)
        val csr = db.query("sqlite_master", null, null, null, null, null, null)
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            for (s in entityList) {
                if (s.toLowerCase() == csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("name")).toLowerCase()) {
                    matchcount++
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        csr.close()
        db.close()
    } catch (e: SQLiteException) {
        return false;
    }
    return matchcount != entityList.size
}
```

- Note that this calls the previous function.